# If $w$ is a zero of $f$ prove that $|f(z)|\leq \left|\frac{z-w}{z-\overline{w}}\right|$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question**

Let $f$ be analytic in the upper half plane and suppose that $|f(z)|<1$ for $z$ in the upper half plane. Prove that if $w$ is a zero of $f$ then $$|f(z)|\leq \left|\frac{z-w}{z-\overline{w}}\right|$$ for all $z$ in the upper half plane.

**Attempt**

I am trying to bring in the zero of $f$ into Schwarz lemma but I am not succeeding so I think I need a hint to get going in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use a Mobius transformation to transform $z$ from the upper half plane to the unit disk with $w\to0$. Apply the Schwartz lemma.

Comment: @user210552: Please accept my answer if you like it.